# SharePoint 2010 WCF RESTful Authentication Issue with Anonymous Authentication Publishing Site

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, restful-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site with Allow Anonymous Access turned on and I am having some problems with using the WCF RESTful data access...

First when I try to create a datasource in Visual Studio 2010 to listdata.svc it fails unless I go into IIS and disable Anonymous Authentication on the _vti_bin. If I disable Anonymous Authentication on the _vti_bin I am able to add the datasource without error.

Second if I have Anonymous Authentication disabled on the _vti_bin and try to connect with SharePoint Designer I get an error after being prompted for my Username/password.

Third if I have Anonymous Authentication allowed on the _vti_bin and try to run my WCF RESTful code it appears that the credentials that are passed in are not used. See Code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        MySite.MySiteDataContext dc = new MySite.MySiteDataContext(new Uri("http://mysite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/"));

        dc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");


        var q = from m in dc.Products
                select m;


        foreach (var i in q)
        { 

           //never gets in here when Anonymous Authentication is allowed on the _vti_bin       
           //when Anonymous Authentication is disabled on _vti_bin this code runs without issue. 

        }
    }
```

So... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or if there is a work around for this issue?

Environment:

SharePoint 2010
Publishing Site with Anonymous Access Turned On
Code running in console application not on same server as SharePoint Server.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a binding as mentioned below.

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int64.MaxValue; 
basicHttpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedResponse; 
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows; 
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("yoururl"); 
basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0); 
basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0); 
basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10,## Heading ## 0, 0);
basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0, 0); 
DataService.ServiceClient obj = new DataService.ServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, endpoint);
```